# Implementation of a dictation system using Sphinx4 and Python

Tags: java, python, speech-recognition, sphinx4, dictation

I want to develop a dictation system using Sphinx4. After some search, I realize that the language that it's better to use is Java. Can I combine Sphinx4 with Python? I prefer Python because I want to enhance my system by adding neural network techniques in the language model and apply domain classification. Also, I read about pocket-sphinx and pypi but pocket-sphinx is said to be for portable lightweight applications while my application will run on the cloud and I will have enough computing power to support a better model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cloud applications it's better to use something like https://github.com/alumae/kaldi-gstreamer-server

Comment: I know and thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it is asked that Sphinx should be used and I wanted to write Python and avoid Java.

Comment: This thing is exactly in Python